# RDS Proxy giving error after few minutes of successful connection

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds-proxy

I have created AWS RDS proxy for python project. The RDS has been built on Postgres database. After successful connection and working, our python project gives error mentioned below.

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly`

I am finding the exact reason for this error.

Comment: SAME! Well almost.

Comment: We're using RDS IAM Auth to connect, and I get this SSL connection issue immediately upon connecting. The database is able to use IAM Auth and SSL to connect fine when connecting to the RDS Instance Endpoint directly, and, I'm able to use psql to connect to the database as well. Totally lost.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?